# Font Awesome Icons in CSS - Larger Sizes

Tags: css, fontawesome-4.4.0

I am using this in my CSS:

```
#ribbon h2:before { 
  content: '\f145';
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #FFF;
}
```

I'd like the icon to be larger using what's here: 
http://fontawesome.io/examples/

```
<i class="fa fa-ticket fa-lg"></i> fa-lg
<i class="fa fa-ticket fa-2x"></i> fa-2x
<i class="fa fa-ticket fa-3x"></i> fa-3x
<i class="fa fa-ticket fa-4x"></i> fa-4x
<i class="fa fa-ticket fa-5x"></i> fa-5x
```

But I cannot figure out how to mix these codes so I can make the icon larger since one uses numbers and one uses text code. What should my CSS look like if I want to use fa-2x for example?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you. i used the code below, but I was really asking how to use "fa fa-ticket fa-lg" for example in the CSS rather than '\f145';

Or how I can also add effects like spinning or whatever. Some simple way to translate all the options here http://fontawesome.io/examples/

into CSS styling - not hard coded HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean but you can increase the icon sizes by increasing the `font-size`.

You  can also create your own classes with various font sizes and assign them to change the icon sizes.


Example:

HTML:

```
<i class="fa fa-ticket fa-6x"></i>
```

CSS:

```
.fa-6x
{
    font-size: 6em; /* x6 larger icon */
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. i used your code to increase the size. Worked great. 

but I was really asking how to use "fa fa-ticket fa-lg" for example in the CSS rather than '\f145';

Or how I can also add effects like spinning or whatever. Some simple way to translate all the options here http://fontawesome.io/examples/

into CSS styling - not hard coded HTML.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with Font Awesome. If this is so important to you and you're open to using another font for achieving it, I suggest you check out [Google's icon font](https://design.google.com/icons/).